# IE10/Safari Cannot Hide an Object/Flash inside of iFrame

Tags: javascript, css, flash, iframe, internet-explorer-10

I have a Flash Animation inside of iFrame. And when I try to hide it, IE10 keep it displayed and overlapping other content.

```
<body style="background-color: #EEE">
    Testing IE10
    <div id="swfDiv">
        <iframe src="swf.html" width="500" height="50"></iframe>
        <br />
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('swfDiv').style.display='none'">Hide</button>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #DDD">
        This try to hide the animation, but it is not working on IE10.  <br/> It works fine in others browsers and earlier versions of IE.
    </div>
</body>
```

[image: IE10]

**Update 02/08/2013**
I found the same problem in Safari (5.1.7)
[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion : **stop using inline javascript**. Another suggestion : **stop using getElementById**. Another one : **validate your code**.

Comment: @MilchePatern although I agree on inline javascript, what's wrong with getElementById?? It's the native way of selecting an element

Comment: This isn't an answer to the bug, just a reponse to your comments:
onlick="Javascript: this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the best solution will be move it off the screen:

```
.xhide
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left:-9999px;
}
```

We can add this class on click to hide it, something like:

```
document.getElementById('swfDiv').className = "xhide";
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigating away before closing the iframe solved my problem on a XBAP, I think it will work for flash too

```
var $iframe = $("#id");
$iframe[0].src = 'about:blank';
$iframe.remove();
```